# Pandas: let two lines auto scale to view the trend clearly

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Suppose I have a dataframe `df` which has two columns, `100cos(x)` and `sin(x)`, if I plot it in one graph, it is not easy to view the trend of the second compare with first.  **How can I autoscale the second one? I just want to view the trend.**

Here is the code to illustrate my point:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(0,4*np.pi,0.02)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sin':np.sin(x), 'Cos':100*np.cos(x)},index=x )
df.Sin.plot()
df.Cos.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

I want the blue line also takes almost the whole picture, please do not just multiply it by a number, the point is `auto` as if I just plot a single blue line in the figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you are too lazy to type much, consider the following solution, which does not need any extra line; just replace `df.Cos.plot()` by `df.Cos.plot(ax=plt.gca().twinx(), color="C1")`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(0,4*np.pi,0.02)
df = pd.DataFrame({'Sin':np.sin(x), 'Cos':100*np.cos(x)},index=x )
df.Sin.plot()
df.Cos.plot(ax=plt.gca().twinx(), color="C1")
plt.show()
```

[image]

However, I would strongly recommend looking closer at the matplotlib example, cited in epattaros answer, to understand what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution to that would be to use two different Y scales, one on each side, [example from matplotlib page](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
s1 = np.exp(t)
ax1.plot(t, s1, 'b-')
ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
# Make the y-axis label, ticks and tick labels match the line color.
ax1.set_ylabel('exp', color='b')
ax1.tick_params('y', colors='b')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
s2 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
ax2.plot(t, s2, 'r.')
ax2.set_ylabel('sin', color='r')
ax2.tick_params('y', colors='r')

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I found this one, I hope something more handy

Comment: what do you mean by handy? whats the issue with this approach?

Comment: such that don't need so much type, one command stuff. Something add one or two lines in my code.

Comment: that can be easily done without "much typing". the only reason there is "much typing" there is because the person creates the variables to plot, and edit the plot. you can easily replicate it in about 3-4 lines to your case.